# where to save the downloaded data?

Tags: java, android, json, api, static

I download big json files 8x(2mb) and used Gson to convert them into java objects. Now I need to make these objects available to all the activities. is it safe to save them as static variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be very lucky to avoid the out of the memory exception.

I would probably store the object to Room database(or any sort of SQL) while parsing and read when required.

Or just store the JSON as a binary file and read again necessary bits when its required since I don't know the usage of the JSON data I can't comment on more... But definitely avoid storing in the static variables.